# Smooth way to store enum to a DB

Tags: c#, sql, database, enums, sql-server-2014

I have an *enum* like so.

```
public enum TimeFrame
{
  Morning = 1,
  Afternoon,
  Evening
}
```

When an object containing a property of type *TimeFrame* is stored, there's a conversion using a *switch* statement making each value explicitly to 1, 2, and 3. The command string created is substituted from e.g. *Evening* to 3. The same when fetching from the DB - if there's a value of 1, it's being mapped manually and explicitly into *Morning*.

Is there a smooth way to storage the values of the *enum* "as is"? Or should we avoid doing so for a reason?

I've tried straight-off approach but that only gives the fall-back value all the way...

```
TimeFrame = row["TimeFrame"] as TimeFrame? ?? TimeFrame.Morning
```

Comment: Downvoter: care to help improve the question?

Comment: What is the Type of row["TimeFrame"] and will it always have a value in the database or can it exist as null?

Comment: @musicfuel It's an *enum*. I challenge you to set it to *null*. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast enums to ints and vice versa, this is very fast. You can also convert between enums and strings, takes a bit more code, time, and storage. You can then trivially store ints or strings in your database.

Comment: I fail to see why casting could be a problem.

Comment: When working on a more "dynamic" date model, there's sometimes a moronic idiot who changes the types back and forth without correcting the code relying on it. There are also forgetful lazies who don't protect casts by a try/catch statement. Oh, the worst part - on occasion, those people are me...   :D

Comment: Use Entity Framework then. Automatically detects schema/data model inconsistencies and saves you a lot of work by handling the database for you.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason the O/R-mapper (or whatever technology you are using) cannot handle enum values, you can create an `int` property translating your enum:

```
// Do not map!
public TimeFrame TimeFrame { get; set; }

// Map!
public int TimeFrameInt {
    get { return (int)TimeFrame; }
    set { TimeFrame = (TimeFrame)value; }
}
```

The translation between ints and enums is simply done with casts; no switch statements required. This is possible and very fast, since enums are represented by ints under the hood.